# bash command to repeatedly emulate keypress on a proceess

Tags: bash, unix, shell, command-prompt, expect

The
**nmap** tool has such a feature - when you're performing a scan [#nmap -A -T4 localhost] and press "Enter" - it displays kind of status information "Timing: About 6.17% done"

Question - how can I force this keypress to happen repeatedly without touching a keyboard in bourne shell?

ps: just trying to find a work-around for a bug in php's proc_open function, when stdout of a process is returned only after closing stdout pipe, and php's pty emulation doesn't work on fbsd.

**Question closed. Problem solved with the "expect" utility**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect

spawn /usr/local/bin/nmap -A -T4 -p 21-100 localhost
expect arting {sleep 3; send \r}
while {1} {
        expect eof {
            send_user "finished\n";
            exit;
        } "done;" {
            sleep 3;
            send \r;
            continue;
        }

}
```

Comment: Are you falling foul of some output buffering? Try fflush() perhaps?

Comment: Since you did use an expect-based solution, please give Douglas the appropriate bonus by selecting his answer as the one that helped.  It was good that you added your solution to the question - thank you for doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably easiest to use [`expect`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the ultimate 'yes man' program will do what you need - the program is called 'yes' and repeatedly generates the same input line over and over.

```
yes ok | recalcitrant.php
```

This will send 'ok' plus newline to the recalcitrant PHP frequently.  It is rate-limited by the speed at which the receiving program reads its inputs.  It is available in the GNU utilities, and on most other Unix-based platforms.

If you need any intelligence in the processing, though, then the Tcl-based '[expect](http://expect.nist.gov/)'

Comment: nope - this one doesn't work either. I'm now trying now to dig deeper into the "expect" world

Comment: @johnrembo: in all honesty, I'm not very surprised that it doesn't do what you need.  Indeed, I don't think  I've often found it useful.  Nevertheless it exists and _if_ it does what you need, there isn't anything much simpler.  But if you need any adaptability in the output, then 'expect' is probably what you need.

Comment: and still - I found "yes" utility pretty usefull (well, not for this particular case) - can't imagine how I didn't knew of existance of such until now (yes, was using a cup of coppe placed over the "enter" key)

Answer (score 1):

Note, you can get rid of the infinite loop:

```
spawn /usr/local/bin/nmap -A -T4 -p 21-100 localhost
expect arting {sleep 3; send \r}
expect {
    "done;" {
        sleep 3
        send \r
        exp_continue
    }
    eof
}
puts "finished"
```

Are you sure you need the `sleep`s?  They can usually be avoided by using `-regexp` matching with the `expect` command.

Helpful Expect tip: while developing, use `exp_internal 1` to verbosely see how your patterns are matching the command output.